# How can I get only one level of objects in a S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to list only the objects in a bucket that aren't buckets themselves.  Is there a way of doing this short of parsing out the results of ListBucket?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> objects in a bucket that aren't buckets themselves

Buckets can't contain other buckets. Do you mean folders? S3 doesn't have a concept of folders either.

You can have 100 buckets per S3 account and each bucket can contain an unlimited number of objects/files. If you name your files with `/`'s in the filename, the AWS GUI tools (eg AWS Console, BucketExplorer etc) will interpret each section as a virtual folder. eg

A file named `folder1/folder2/myfile.jpg` will be stored in S3 as a 'flat' file with that name, but in the GUI tools it will appear as though a file named `myfile.jpg` is 2 subfolders down in `folder1/folder2`.

You can use the `prefix` and `delimiter` parameters to parse the results of a [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html) call. The same options are available in any of the SDKs too.

**UPDATE** to answer comment.

Assuming our S3 bucket looks like this:

```
mybucket
   folder1
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      folder2
          file3.txt
          file4.txt
      folder3
          file5.txt
          file6.txt
```

Using **`prefix = "folder1/"`** would return all 6 files : `file1.txt` to `file6.txt`.

Using a **`prefix = "folder1/"`** and a **`delimiter = "/"`** would return 2 files:

```
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
```

And the `CommonPrefixes` collection of the response with contain

```
    folder1/folder2/
    folder1/folder3/
```

Comment: To rephrase my question then, what delimiter would I use in your example so that I only see only those at folder2 deep, but not myfile.jpg?

Comment: @Graham - I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Geoff Appleford, could you answer my issue? please help thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639195/how-can-i-get-objects-in-a-s3-bucket

Comment: Looks like you can have 1000 buckets if you ask nicely https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: +1 for simply ending with a slash. In other words, listing all files in a (virtual) directory only works with the slash at the end: `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/my-dir/`

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for solving the same problem "*To list first/root/x level directory only*" and finally stumbled into something called "Paginator".

```
$results = $s3Client->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
    'Bucket'    => 'my-bucket',
    'Delimiter' => '/'
]);

$expression = '[CommonPrefixes[].Prefix, Contents[].Key][]';
foreach ($results->search($expression) as $item) {
    echo $item . "\n";
}
```

I tested it and works exactly as expected! :)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_paginators.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a better approach using the latest `boto3` version (1.14 as of now) and [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) method.

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=your_prefix)

print(response)
```