# Retrieve list of only root objects (folders) in S3 - aws sdk v3 php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given my S3 bucket that contains images in a structure like so:

```
root/portraits/portrait_001.jpg
root/landscapes/landscape_001.jpg
```

where root is my bucket, and there are no other files in my root, just those folders (objects), how do I retrieve a list of just those objects?

```
portraits/
landscapes/
```

I am familiar with using the Delimiter and Prefix in the ListObjects call.

If I do the following, I get no results:

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Delimiter' => '/',
));

foreach($objects as $object)
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
```

If I don't use a Delimiter, I get everything, obviously.

I cannot use a prefix because the objects I desire are root-level. Otherwise, I have no problem using the prefix to say, list just the files in 'portraits/'

From my searches, I've only managed to find solutions from previous years that only apply to the aws php sdk v1 or v2, and I have had no luck in trying those (v3 is quite different)

Any suggestions? I feel like I'm missing something simple, but searching through the documentation, I can't find anything to help me. As a last resort, I'll just have to stick with manually declaring an array

```
$categories = ['portraits/', 'landscapes/']
```

But that isn't ideal in the case where I want to add more categories in the future, and not have to worry about adding another category manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit - Solution**

I must have been looking in the wrong places during my object dumps, but eventually saw the Common Prefixes in the returned result from a ListObjects call with a delimiter of '/', like so:

```
$s3->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'Delimiter' => '/'));
```

Comment: Have you tried using the list of `CommonPrefixes` returned from `ListBucket`? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Comment: Originally I couldn't find the common prefixes anywhere, but maybe I was overlooking that during my object dumps in the wrong places. I just found them now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Paginator with the following expression '[CommonPrefixes[].Prefix, Contents[].Key][]' also helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245799/1172872

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directories do not actually exist in Amazon S3. However, the Management Console allows the creation of folders, and paths are supported to give the illusion of directories.

For example, object `bar.jpg` stored in the `foo` directory has a path of `/foo/bar.jpg`. The trick is that the object is actually called `foo/bar.jpg` rather than just `bar.jpg`. Most users wouldn't even notice the difference.

From the API, the ability to list directories is provided via the concept of `CommonPrefixes`, which look the same as directory paths and consist of the portion of object names ('keys') before the final slash.

See: [Listing Keys Hierarchically Using a Prefix and Delimiter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed the correct request is as follows (sorry to write it in typescript, but the idea should apply to PHP as well).

```
const request = new ListObjectsV2Command({ Bucket: 'bucketName', Delimiter: '/' });
const response = await s3Client.send(request);

const folders = response.CommonPrefixes;
```

The response of the afore cited request as as follows:

```json
{
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "rootFolder1/"
        },
        {
            "Prefix": "rootFolder2/"
        },
        {
            "Prefix": "rootFolder3/"
        }
    ],
    "Delimiter": "/",
    "IsTruncated": false,
    "KeyCount": 4,
    "MaxKeys": 1000,
    "Name": "bucketName",
    "Prefix": ""
}
```