# AWS S3 get all files by suffix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On S3 I have the following structure

```
/folder1
  /index.yaml
  /somefile.csv
/folder2
  /index.yaml
  /anotherfile.png
/folder3
  /file.xml
```

I need to get all files with a name `index.yaml` by using `ListObjectsV2Command`. Currently the command accepts a `Prefix` parameter, but I need a suffix parameter. So I wonder is it even possible to do what I need?

Basically what I need to return is:

```
/folder1/index.yaml
/folder2/index.yaml
```

If there is no way than the only solution is reading all files? But it is difficult to believe that it is not implemented on AWS..

### EDIT:

The only workaround I can think of is getting a list of all root directories (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77554035/13179254) and then looping over it and try to get the content of `index.yaml`, but having a parameter `Suffix` for `ListObjectsV2Command` could be a better solution.

Comment: Prefix only. No way without listing entire bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it seems that there is no option for search by `Suffix`, so I have come up with a workaround which works for my case.

```js
// Get all root folders
const request = new ListObjectsV2Command({ Bucket: 'bucketName', Delimiter: '/' });
const response = await s3Client.send(request);

for (const prefix of response.CommonPrefixes) {
    const contentRequest = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: 'bucketName', Key: prefix.Prefix + 'index.yaml' }); 
    const contentResponse = await s3Client.send(contentRequest);
    const stringContent = await contentResponse?.Body?.transformToString();

    if (stringContent?.length) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```